# Prove that:$\int_a^bp(x)f(x)dx \int_a^bp(x)g(x)dx\leq\int_a^bp(x)dx\int_a^bp(x)f(x)g(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, integral-inequality

Problem:

> For continuous, either both increasing or both decreasing functions $f, g$ on $[a, b]$, suppose that $p(x)$ is continuous and positive. Prove that
>   $$\int_a^bp(x)f(x)dx \int_a^bp(x)g(x)dx\leq\int_a^bp(x)dx\int_a^bp(x)f(x)g(x)dx$$

I don't know what I can do. I think the monotonic property of $f, g$ will be used but I have no idea. Can anyone give me hints?

Comment: Just for the reference: If $p$ is normalized to satisfy $\int_{a}^{b}p(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=1$, then this inequality is called [the Harris inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKG_inequality#A_special_case:_the_Harris_inequality).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can proceed similarly as in the proof of the [Integral Chebyshev inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Integral_Chebyshev_inequality), see for example

- [Given two increasing continuous functions $f,g$ prove that $(b-a) \int^b_a f(x)g(x) dx > \int^b_a f(x) dx \int^b_a g(x) dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163512/given-two-increasing-continuous-functions-f-g-prove-that-b-a-intb-a-fxg).

In your case, you use the fact that the monotonicity of $f$ and $g$
(and the positivity of $p$) implies that
$$ 
  0 \le p(x) p(y) \bigl(f(x) - f(y) \bigr)  \bigl(g(x) - g(y) \bigr)
$$
for all $x, y \in [a, b]$. Integrating this relationship
over $[a,b] \times [a, b]$ yields exactly the wanted inequality
$$
\int_a^bp(x)f(x) \, dx \int_a^bp(x)g(x) \, dx \le
\int_a^bp(x) \, dx \int_a^bp(x)f(x)g(x) \, dx \, .
$$