# $\int_0^1f(x)\cdot x^{n+1}\text{d}x > \int_0^1f(x)\cdot x^n\text{d}x \cdot \int_0^1f(x)\cdot x\text{d}x$

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality

I have convinced myself that
$$\int_0^1f(x)\cdot x^{n+1}\text{d}x > \int_0^1f(x)\cdot x^n\text{d}x \cdot \int_0^1f(x)\cdot x\text{d}x$$
is true whenever

- $f$ is non-negative,
- $\int_0^1f(x)\text{d}x=1$, and
- it is not the case that $f(x)=\delta(x-c)$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function and $c$ is a constant in $[0,1]$ (in which case it is obvious that equality holds instead).

However, I could use some help proving it. I would be very happy just to get a hint - no full solution needed.

Btw, if there's someone who think they can help but don't know what the Dirac delta function is, then just assume that $f$ is a normal function and ignore the last condition.

Comment: Related: [Prove that:$\int_a^bp(x)f(x)dx \int_a^bp(x)g(x)dx\leq\int_a^bp(x)dx\int_a^bp(x)f(x)g(x)dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1839878/42969)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably $n > 0$ here.

This is essentially a special case of the Harris inequality for the probability measure $f(x)\; dx$ on $[0,1]$.  For any strictly increasing functions $g$ and $h$ we have

$$ \int_0^1 f(x) g(x) h(x)\; dx > \int_0^1 f(x) g(x)\; dx \cdot \int_0^1 f(x) h(x)\; dx $$
which follows from
$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 (g(x)-g(y))(h(x)-h(y)) f(x) f(y)\; dx \; dy > 0$$