# Show that $\int_0^1 x\,g(x)f(x)dx \ge \bigg(\int_0^1 x\,f(x)dx\bigg)\bigg(\int_0^1 g(x)f(x)dx\bigg)$ for pdf $f(x)$ and non-decreasing $g(x)$

Tags: calculus, inequality, probability-distributions

Given a pdf $f(x)$ for $x\in [0,1]$, and a non-decreasing function $g(x)$ bounded between $0$ and $1$, how do I prove the following inequality?

$$ \int_0^1 x\,g(x)f(x)dx \ge \bigg(\int_0^1 x\,f(x)dx\bigg)\bigg(\int_0^1 g(x)f(x)dx\bigg) $$

Conversely, if $g(x)$ is non-increasing instead, then the relationship becomes

$$ \int_0^1 x\,g(x)f(x)dx \le \bigg(\int_0^1 x\,f(x)dx\bigg)\bigg(\int_0^1 g(x)f(x)dx\bigg) $$

I'm guessing there must be a theorem that deals with this kind of expressions but I do not know about it.

Comment: This is an example of [Harris's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKG_inequality#A_special_case:_the_Harris_inequality). The usual proof goes by noting that $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}[x - y][g(x)-g(y)] f(x)f(y) \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \geq 0 $$ and then rearranging this inequality.

Comment: Looks also like  special case of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1839878/42969

Comment: thank you, I wasn't able to find a similar answer already. It seemed logical that this was a solved problem but I didn't know the name for it.