# Prove $\int_{0}^{1}f^{3}(x)dx\geq 4\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}f(x)dx\int_{0}^{1}xf^{2}(x)dx$

Tags: integration, inequality, definite-integrals, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,\infty)$ continuous function. Show that

$$\int_{0}^{1}f^{3}(x)dx\geq 4\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}f(x)dx\int_{0}^{1}xf^{2}(x)dx$$

This problem is from American Mathematical Monthly, 2015. I proved that

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}f(x)dx-\int_{0}^{1}xf^{2}(x)dx\leq \frac{1}{16}$$

This is a result from a Putnam problem. By Cauchy-Schwarz ineqaulity (using the fact that $f$ is positive), it is easy to show $$\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}f(x)dx\int_{0}^{1}f^{3}(x)dx\geq \left ( \int_{0}^{1}xf^{2}(x)dx \right )$$

and

$$\int_{0}^{1}f^{3}(x)dx\geq \int_{0}^{1}f^{2}(x)dx\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$$

I don't know if these results are helpful for this problem. Another interesting thing that I found is

$$\int_{0}^{1}xf^{2}(x)dx-\int_{0}^{1}f^{3}(x)dx\leq \frac{1}{12}$$

Maybe that $4$ in the main ineqality is from a quadratic equation discriminant? Maybe we need to make some parameters and use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality? Can somemone give me a hint for this problem? I would appreciate!

Comment: This is not a hint to a possible answer, just poiting out a probable typo. In the title of the question, you have $4$ in the RHS of the inequality, which doesn't appear in the post.

Comment: @xyz Thanks. Now the question is alright.

Answer (score 7):

It follows directly from [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality), which gives
$$
\int_0^1 x^2 f \leq \left(\int_0^1 f^3\right)^{1/3} \left(\int_0^1 x^3\right)^{2/3} = \frac{1}{4^{2/3}} \left(\int_0^1 f^3\right)^{1/3}
$$
and
$$
\int_0^1 x f^2 \leq \left(\int_0^1 f^3\right)^{2/3} \left(\int_0^1 x^3\right)^{1/3} = \frac{1}{4^{1/3}} \left(\int_0^1 f^3\right)^{2/3}
$$
and multiplying the above inequalities give the result.

---

**Remark:** the constant is optimal, since there is equality whenever $f(x) = x$.

Answer (score 1):

One can proceed similarly as in

- [Prove that:$\int_a^bp(x)f(x)dx \int_a^bp(x)g(x)dx\leq\int_a^bp(x)dx\int_a^bp(x)f(x)g(x)dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1839878/42969),

which is a variant of the [Integral Chebyshev inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Integral_Chebyshev_inequality).

For $x, y \in (0, 1]$ are the two terms
$$
 \frac{f(x)}{x} - \frac{f(y)}{y} \text{ and } \frac{f(x)^2}{x^2} - \frac{f(y)^2}{y^2}
$$
simultaneously negative, zero, or positive, so that their product is always nonnegative. It follows that
$$ 
 0 \le \bigl(y f(x) -x f(y) \bigr) \cdot \bigl(y^2 f(x)^2 - x^2 f(y)^2 \bigr) \\
= y^3 f(x)^3 - x^2 f(x) y f(y)^2 -  y^2 f(y) x f(x)^2 + x^3 f(y)^3
$$
and that holds for $x=0$ or $y=0$ as well.

Integrating this relationship over $(x, y) \in [0, 1]^2$ gives
$$
 0 \le 2 \left( \int_0^1 y^3 \, dy \cdot \int_0^1 f(x)^3 \, dx
- \int_0^1 x^2 f(x) \, dx \cdot \int_0^1 y f(y)^2 \, dy \right)
$$
which is the desired inequality.

Equality holds exactly if $f(x)/x$ is constant, that is for $f(x) = cx$ with some $c \ge 0$.