# Integral of point-wise product of 2 functions greater than product of 2 integrals

Tags: calculus, inequality, integral-inequality

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous increasing functions defined on $[0,1]$. Prove that $$\left(\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx\right)\left(\int_0^1 g(x)\,dx\right) \le \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\,dx$$

This looks like Cauchy-Schwarz, using $L^1$(?) but that makes little sense to me. 
Perhaps there is a more elementary way of proving this inequality?

Note: This question is from a undergraduate single variable calculus course, but feel free to use any suitable theorems from analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just the continuous version of [Chebyshev's sum inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality), which on its turn is a straightforward consequence of the [rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality).

The continuous version follows from the discrete version by considering Riemann sums (if $\int$ stands for a Riemann integral) or approximations through simple functions (if $\int$ stands for a Lebesgue integral).

Comment: Of course that's not quite a proof; we might note that the continuous version follows from the discrete version by considering Riemann sums. (+1 anyway, since I didn't know either version...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: of course, you are right, answer updated.

Comment: Or by a simple direct calculation as in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1763198/42969 :)

Comment: @MartinR: (+1) to your answer, I did not notice this was a duplicate.