# Mean of product vs. product of means

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals

Using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we can prove that
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b f(x)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x \geq \left( \frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \right)^2.
\end{equation}
This is true because
\begin{eqnarray}
\left( \frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \right)^2 &=& \frac{1}{(b-a)^2} \left( \int \limits_a^b f(x) \cdot 1 \, \mathrm{d}x \right)^2\\
&\stackrel{\textrm{C-S}}{\leq}& \frac{1}{(b-a)^2} \int \limits_a^b f(x)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x \underbrace{\int \limits_a^b 1^2 \, \mathrm{d}x }_{b-a} = \frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b f(x)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{eqnarray}
Is the following more general statement also true:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b f(x) g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \geq \frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
(say for non-negative functions to avoid problems)?

In words we would state this as "The mean of the product of two functions is greater or equal than the product of the means of the two functions", which is true if both functions are the same.

Any hint on how to prove or disprove this would be appreciated.

Comment: No. (You can easily have $fg=0$ identically for not-identically-zero $f$ and $g$.)

Comment: Or: you are asking us to prove the covariance is always nonnegative, which is nonsense.

Comment: Also, the inequality of the first line is Jensen with the convex function $x\mapsto x^2$

Comment: These are all great remarks which I hadn't thought of! Thank you metamorphy, user10354138 and Maximilian Janisch.

Comment: The second inequatily is the [“integral Chebyshev inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Integral_Chebyshev_inequality) and holds if both functions are increasing (or both decreasing). See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1163512/42969.

Comment: Thank you Martin R – your comment helps a lot with my original problem, from which I derived my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b f(x) g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \geq \frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
is **false** in general, even for strictly positive functions $f$ and $g$. To see this we first write the difference in the form
\begin{eqnarray}
&& \frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b f(x) g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x - \frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x\\
&& = \frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b \left( f(x) - \frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \right) \left( g(x) - \frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \right) \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{eqnarray}
The last expression may be negative in general, for example with
\begin{equation}
f(x) := 1+\frac{x-a}{b-a}, \quad g(x) := 2-\frac{x-a}{b-a}
\end{equation}
(strictly positive on $[a,b]$). We obtain
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{3}{2},
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b \left( f(x) - \frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \right) \left( g(x) - \frac{1}{b-a} \int \limits_a^b g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \right) \, \mathrm{d}x = -\frac{1}{12} < 0,
\end{equation}
so this is a counterexample.

However, if $f, g$ are *monotonic functions of the same monotonicity,* then the statement holds and is called the [integral Chebyshev inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Integral_Chebyshev_inequality).

Thanks for the helpful comments!