# Show that: $\int_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)dx\ .\ \int_{0}^{1}g\left(x\right)dx\ \le\ \int_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)dx$

Tags: real-analysis

Given f and g defined in $ [0,1] $ continuous and increasing in that interval.
Show that: $\int_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)dx\ .\ \int_{0}^{1}g\left(x\right)dx\ \le\ \int_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)dx$

I've looked everywhere about the properties of integrals but I haven't found this one. Why?

Comment: Could you give us some more context? Where did you encounter this problem? Are there any results or techniques that you know about that might be useful here?

Comment: Because this is a special case of a bigger inequality. And it might not be useful for undergraduate courses.

Comment: (And that inequality can also be generalized into aother bigger thing)

Comment: @phsubi To give you more information, you should refer to the integral version of Chebyshev's sum inequality. The assumption of continuity on your two functions is superfluous, what is essential is that they both be integrable and monotonic of the same monotony (either both increasing or both decreasing).

Comment: [Chebyshev sum/integral inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given two increasing continuous functions $f,g$ prove that $(b-a) \int^b_a f(x)g(x) dx >\int^b_a f(x) dx \int^b_a g(x) dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163512/given-two-increasing-continuous-functions-f-g-prove-that-b-a-intb-a-fxg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f, g$ are continuous, there exists $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|, |g(x)| \leq M, \forall x \in [0, 1]$. Consider $$\int_0^1 f(x) dx \int_0^1 g(x) dx \leq \int_0^1 f(x) g(x) dx \iff \int_0^1 (f(x)-M) \int_0^1 (g(x)+M) dx \leq \int_0^1 (f(x)-M)(g(x)+M) dx$$ we can assume that $f \leq 0$ and $g \geq 0$.

Let $H(x) := \int_0^x f(t)g(t) dt - \int_0^x f(t) dt \int_0^x g(t) dt$. Then $H'(x) = f(x)g(x) - f(x)\int_0^x g(t)dt - g(x)\int_0^x f(t)dt = (f(x) - \int_0^x f(t) dt)(g(x) - \int_0^x g(t) dt) - \int_0^xf(t) dt \int_0^x g(t) dt \geq 0, \forall x \in (0, 1)$.

Hence, the inequality holds.

Comment: Why is the last expression $\ge 0$? I am probably missing something obvious.

Comment: Since $f, g$ are increasing, $f(x) - \int_0^x f(t) dt \geq 0, g(x) - \int_0^x g(t) dt \geq 0$. By the assumption, $f \leq 0, g \geq 0$, $\int_0^x f(t)dt \leq 0, \int_0^x g(t) dt \geq 0$.

Comment: Yes you are right. It's my mistake. Since $g \geq 0$, $g(x) - \int_0^x g(t) dt \geq xg(x)-x\int_0^x g(t) dt = x(g(x) - \int_0^x g(t) dt) \geq 0$ but it is not true for $f$.