# Show Product of Integrals $\leq$ Integral of Products, $f,g$ continuous and increasing, using Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

I came across a problem from a student I was helping and got stumped myself:

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous increasing functions on $[0,1]$. Prove that:

$\int_0^1 f(x)dx \int_0^1 g(x)dx \leq \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx $

There is a hint to use Mean Value Theorem.

I defined $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt$ and similarly for $G(x)$, and applying Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we get that  $\int_0^1 f(x)dx \int_0^1 g(x)dx = (F(1) - F(0))(G(1)-G(0))$

Applying MVT, we get that there exists some $c_1$ such that $f(c_1) = (F(1) - F(0)) / (1-0)$ so $f(c_1) = F(1)-F(0)$ and similarly for $c_2, g$ and $G$.

Plugging in we get that $\int_0^1 f(x)dx \int_0^1 g(x)dx = f(c_1) g(c_2)$

Now, how would we relate this to $\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx $ with an inequality? Trying to integrate by parts doesn't seem promising, nor does trying to define an antiderivative $H(x)$ for the integral of the product - but perhaps I'm missing something. I'm not sure how to use the fact that $f,g$ are increasing - this means $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ are convex on this interval, so is that where the inequality comes from?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1163512/42969 for two different proofs. One of them uses the mean value theorem.